# How does tensorflow deal with 2-dimensional errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, gradient-descent

Say I I have a simple AND neuron using SGD:

```
data = np.array([
    (0, 0),
    (0, 1),
    (1, 0),
    (1, 1),
])

labels = np.array([
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [1],
])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

w = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[-0.31199348], [-0.46391705]], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=[-1.94877], dtype=tf.float32)
h = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(x, w), b) 

error = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=h)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer().minimize(error)
```

As a result I will have 2-dimensional error:

```
In [0]: error.get_shape()
Out[0]: TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(1)])
```

If I check gradient of `error` w.r.t. `w` using simple script:

```
In [1]: print sess.run(
            tf.gradients(error, w), 
            feed_dict={
                x: data, 
                y: labels,
            },
        )
```

I will see following:

```
Out[1]: array([[-0.8440423 ], [-0.85625702]]
```

Now if I change `error` to calculate `mean` across batches:

```
In [2]: error = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=h), 
            reduction_indices=0,
        )
```

I will have a single-dimensional `error`:

```
In [3]: error.get_shape()
Out[3]: (1,)
```

Using the same script I will see different result:

```
Out[4]: [[-0.21101058], [-0.21406426]]
```

Which actually makes perfect sense since now it is the same result divided by 4 (batch size) - that's what mean really is.

What I can't understand is how tensorflow calculated gradients in the first case with 2-dimensional `error` (where basically we have several errors instead of a single one)? It would seem reasonable to me if it implicitly calculated mean across first dimension (batches), but as we can see it's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Now I have an answer: tensorflow simply sums errors across first dimension, i.e. batches.